# Is there a way to programmatically access change sets as records?

Tags: soql, change-set

Is there any way to access a change set and its components from a SOQL query or any other programmatic method?

Comment: What kind of access are you aiming for? You can pull the contents of a changeset via the Metadata API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Treat change set as an unmanaged package/manage package. You can extract all the metadata as a zip using the package name. Workbench already supports this and also the CLI

You can use the Salesforce(sfdx) CLI to do this using below (It uses metadata api under the hood)

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg -u <username> -p <change set name>
```

This will retrieve the package.xml in zip file and that can help you get all the components

If you need in SFDX format(this is one the VScode extension for salesforce) supports then use the below command

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n <change set name>
```

Comment: You can also use force:source:retrieve as well, if you prefer DX file format.

Comment: yes good point. Let me add that as well there

Comment: This might be obvious to others, but I think this only works for outbound change sets. I tried this for an inbound change set in prod and it couldn't find the change set. But it worked retrieving it from the sandbox as an outbound change set.